# pygame がインストールできません

Tags: python, python3, pip, pygame

どこを見直すべきでしょうか？

```
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

os は　windows　で、
仮想環境、IDEは無しで
Python 3.11.1です。
コマンドプロンプトからの実行をやってみようと試みた際にできなかったので、質問させていただきました。
最近からプログラミングを始めたため、
まだpip をインストールしたことがありません。
本を参考にしてコマンドを実行したらこうなりまして、
pipがインストールができないと何もできないプログラムを組んでみたので困っているところです。

Comment: インストールの手順や実行環境などを質問に記載しておくと回答が付きやすいと思います。(質問は後からでも [編集] できます)

Comment: 「どこを見直すべきでしょうか？」とのことですが、そもそも上記メッセージは何でしょうか？ OSは何でどんなツールで何をしたらこのメッセージが表示されたのでしょうか？ また、メッセージ内に「See above for details.」とありますので、ログに何か情報が出力されていませんか？

Comment: もしWindowsでPythonの版数が3.11.xだとPyPIに3.11用のwheelファイルが無い [ファイルをダウンロード - pygame 2.1.2](https://pypi.org/project/pygame/#files) のでインストール出来ないかもしれません。こちらの非公式にWindows用バイナリを配布しているサイト [Pygame - Archived: Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) から3.11用のwheelファイルを入手してインストールしてみてください。

Comment: 検索すると解決していませんがこんな記事があります。[Metadata-generation-failed when trying to install pygame \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74397049/9014308), [Python pygame not installing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74188013/9014308) 他にpygameのドキュメンテーションがこちら。[GettingStarted — wiki](https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted) 何かしら参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: 皆様丁寧に情報を教えていただきありがとうございます。

Comment: 早速模索してみます

Comment: wheelファイルを入手してどこにインストールすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: インストール先は特に指定する必要は無いでしょう。ただ特定の仮想環境に入れたいならActivateしてカレント環境の状態でインストールすれば良いでしょう。wheelで入れるならダウンロードして pip install のパラメータにダウンロードしたwheelファイルのフルパス名を指定してください。なおパスの途中のフォルダ名には全角文字や空白は含まない方が良いでしょう。ちなみにOS種類・Python版数・Anaconda/PyCharmなどのIDE有無・仮想環境有無といった情報を質問記事に追記してみてください。

Comment: Python版数は最新の3.11.1ではなく3.10.9に落とした方が良さそうです。参考にしている書籍があるならその情報も追記してみてください。おそらくゲーム作成の本だと思われますが、題名や内容に「ゼロから」と書いてあったとしても、結局のところコンピュータ、プログラミング、Pythonなどに関する基礎的な知識・経験・ノウハウ・Tipsなどは別途習得しておく必要があるでしょう。